# Jinja2 encoding to render

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, ascii, jinja2

I have a python string:

```
<p> <a href="http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/how-to-travel-around-the-world-for-a-year">How to travel around the world for a year • Alex MacCaw<span class="small">blog.alexmaccaw.com</span> </a></p>
```

of 
`<type 'str'>`

the problem is caused by the `•` when I try to render it using Jinja.

```
renderedPage = template.render(starred = the_string_i_mentioned_higher_up)
```

And end up with this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 125: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried all sort of encoding and decoding but I always get a similar error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you get `the_string_i_mentioned_higher_up` or how it is encoded? Are you declaring it literally?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the htmml code:

```
&middot;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `unicode`, not `str` objects for text in Python 2. Especially for text with non-ASCII characters. `str` only works coincidentally, sometimes.

(You also need to specify your source encoding if you have text with non-ASCII in your source file):

```
# coding: utf-8
mystring = u'<p> <a href="http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/how-to-travel-around-the-world-for-a-year">How to travel around the world for a year • Alex MacCaw<span class="small">blog.alexmaccaw.com</span> </a></p>'
```

(It's probably also a Bad Idea to have HTML in your Python code instead of in a template or the database...)